# Unable to log in Windows server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, error-logging

I downloaded .vdmx file with Windows server 2012 installed. The person who used this drive before logged in with domain credentials. Since I have account in the same domain I am encountering the next error "the trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed". Is there default local administartor credentials or some way to log in as local user?

Answer (score 0):

Unless the Windows server was set up as a Domain Controller, the local Administrator (BUILTIN\Administrator) account should have been enabled as part of OOBE and would have required a password to be typed. The server is trying to authenticate your domain credentials against the domain and for some reason the trust has been screwed, you will need to rejoin the machine to your domain.

In the meantime you will be able to log in with any cached domain account if you physically disconnect the machine from the LAN. That way it won't try and authenticate against your domain and will just use the cached copy of the credentials.

Good luck :)